# Name of part of Cormac McCarthy's writing style

Tags: single-word-requests, writing-style, literary-english

Cormac McCarthy has several idiosyncracies in his writing style, but I'm looking for the name of a specific style he employs: When he joins together several actions or clauses with "and".

Example that I just made up: "He walked over to the horse and whispered to it and stroked it and let it know that everything was ok and closed his eyes and…"

I'm fairly certain it has a name, but it escapes me, and it's hard to google the word "and".

Comment: See the accepted answer for the duplicate question.